# How to generate AES secret key and write the key to a file in UNIX

Tags: unix, encryption, aes

I have to generate a random secret key for AES encryption/decryption and write this key to a file in UNIX.Can someone help me to learn how to do this ?

Comment: Just curious... what do you need this for? If you are trying to encrypt a communication, I would suggest using a standard library that already implements SSL rather than rolling your own.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan: i have to do some encryption/decryption through java class. I want the key generation to happen only once and it should be done manually using UNIX command.I will read this secret key from file in java class and perform encryption/decryption.

Comment: `dd bs=1 if=/dev/random of=/home/users/cryptonoob/aes_key count=32`

Answer (score 5):

An **AES key** is just some random bytes, of 16, 24 or 32 bytes length - depending of key size, and can in principle be stored in the file system as an binary file. However I do recommend that you put it in a Java Key Store, and protect it by password. You can use the java keytool to do all of this, like this:

```
keytool -genseckey -alias myKey -keyalg AES -keysize 128 -storepass passw0rd -keypass passw0rd -storetype JCEKS -keystore keystore.jks
```

You can then read if from java like:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("keystore.jks"), "passw0rd".toCharArray());
Key key = keyStore.getKey("myKey", "passw0rd".toCharArray());
byte[] raw = key.getEncoded();
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
etc...
```